# got error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

Tags: php

```
foreach($results as $row){
        $id = $row->ID;
        $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT CoachID FROM  edge_user_details WHERE user_id='".$id."'");
        $member_zid = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT zoho_contact_id FROM edge_user_details WHERE user_id='".$id."'");
        $coach_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM edge_CoachList WHERE cid='".$id."'");

        echo $member_zid[0];
        echo "<br/>";
        print_r($coach_id);
```

Comment: Describe Your Question what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

```
echo member_zid->zoho_contact_id;
echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($coach_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little research shows that $wpdb is the database wrapper used by Wordpress.

Judging from your code, I can't exactly tell at what line your error occurs, but I'd guess either `echo $member_zid[0];` or `print_r($coach_id);`.

This happens because the [get_results()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) method returns an object with a result set of rows that your query returned.

I'm guessing you only want to get a single row, so I'd propose using [get_row()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) instead (which returns the first row found by default).

Once you do that, your code would look like this:

```
foreach($results as $row){
   $id = $row->ID;
   $res = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT CoachID FROM  edge_user_details WHERE user_id='".$id."'");
   $member = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT zoho_contact_id FROM edge_user_details WHERE user_id='".$id."'");
   $coach = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT id FROM edge_CoachList WHERE cid='".$id."'");

   echo $member->id;
   echo "<br/>";
   print_r($coach->id)
 }
```

You should really try to add a proper description to your questions. I'm new here myself, but in my opinion that's the least one can expect from someone asking for help.